# Telegram: no answer sent with answerInlineQuery

Tags: rest, telegram, telegram-bot

I make a POST request in response to an inline request with the following url

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<some-token>/answerInlineQuery
```

and body

```
{
    "inline_query_id": "${inline_query_id}",
    "result": {
            "InlineQueryResultArticle": [
                {
                    "type": "article",
                    "id": "111",
                    "title": "some-title",
                    "input_message_content": {"message_text": "TEXT 1"}           
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Telegram responds 200 OK but there is no changes/answers in the bot.

I've also tried so many modifications of the body to sent. No one was successfull, but no one error I`ve got too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this one works.

```
{
        "inline_query_id": "${inline_query_id}",
        "results":  [{
                        "type": "article",
                        "id": "111",
                        "title": "some-title",
                        "input_message_content": {"message_text":"TEXT 1" }          
                    }]
    }
```

It needs **results** instead of **result**. And no definition of InlineQueryResultArticle